# How to find source of non generic functions?

Tags: julia

Find source of generic functions is (thanks to Julia introspection) easy:

```
@edit sizeof("")
```

I see it is defined in `julia/base/strings/string.jl` as

```
sizeof(s::String) = Core.sizeof(s)
```

Is there similar way how to find source of Core.size function?

Help is not very helpful:

```
help?> Core.sizeof
  No documentation found.

  Core.sizeof is a Function.

  # 0 methods for generic function "sizeof":
```

Comment: `grep` in the `/src` and `/base` directories of Julia is one way. In this case, for example, good search strings are `'core("sizeof")'` and `jl_builtin_sizeof`

Comment: Thanks! :) But `jl_builtin_sizeof` is `core("sizeof")` and core is `static jl_value_t *core(const char *name){    return jl_get_global(jl_core_module, jl_symbol(name));}` so path to source code for `Core.sizeof` is still semantically encrypted for me :P

Comment: Greping for `jl_builtin_sizeof` picks a hit in `codegen.cpp` around line 3000, which has some more on how `Core.sizeof` is implemented. But maybe some additional method of annotation (and `help`) is a good future change

Comment: Right, but it is not precisely implementation of this function. It seems to me like code to generate this function. I was expected something similar to `jl_alloc_string` (`src\array.c`) where I could see that first (size_t) bytes of allocated string represents sizeof string. I just wanted to understand how could I "hack" reading of these bytes in Julia code. `@code_llvm sizeof("")` gets other look at `sizeof` implementation, but is is also "encrypted" for me at this time. Thanks again! :) Seems this task is "hacking" too deep to not very well commented files...

Comment: `sizeof` is also a *generic function* in Base (which fallbacks to `Core.sizeof` sometimes). The specific case of `sizeof("")` can be viewed as `@edit sizeof("")` and is indeed a simple `s.len` expression.

Comment: (my comments are for Julia 0.6)

Comment: Interesting! It is not true at least in Version 0.7.0-DEV.2815... But maybe after [this commit](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/e596847b8648529e29a95fe38b4866eff08f41c2#diff-2ac58dca1441c1a860eb7aea2f488dacL62) it could be back? I'll check :)

Comment: latest commit `@edit sizeof("")` gives `sizeof(s::AbstractString) = ncodeunits(s) * sizeof(codeunit(s))` :) ( `ncodeunits(s::String) = Core.sizeof(s)` and `sizeof(codeunit(s))` gives `sizeof(x) = Core.sizeof(x)`). Uff! Is there still `len` field in String? How could I find source code where is String type defined?

Comment: `julia> "aaa".len` => `ERROR: type String has no field len` (returns 3 in Julia 0.6) and there is nothing about it in [news.md](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md) but adding `ncodeunits` is called [library improvements](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md#library-improvements). Maybe specialization for `String` was forgotten?

Comment: Seems like len is still present there in memory: `[unsafe_load(Base.unsafe_convert(Ptr{Int64}, pointer_from_objref("#"^i))) for i in 5000:5010] == collect(5000:5010)` => `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you and Dan Getz worked out in the comments, this is a *builtin* function. Julia has a set of "primitive" functions (a list [starts here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/e48eaaf690b6360ef0dbf140f4db3c2ce5705ea6/base/inference.jl#L646)) which are handled explicitly by Julia's compiler. Many of these map pretty directly to specific [CPU instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings), but in generic form (e.g., addition but generically for all types supported by the CPU & FPU). In very rough terms, Julia's compiler pipeline takes code and transforms it (lowering), performs type inference and inlining, and ultimately reduces it to a set of function calls to either high-level functions (ones that it has not inlined) or the builtins. Perhaps counterintuitively, in most cases *there is no C implementation of the builtins*: instead, the builtin serves merely as a "signal" to the code generator, which takes these greatly-reduced expressions and emits [LLVM IR](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) and lets LLVM generate the native code.  For this specific case of `sizeof`, here is the [code to generate the LLVM IR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/e48eaaf690b6360ef0dbf140f4db3c2ce5705ea6/src/codegen.cpp#L2749-L2800).

There are compelling reasons for doing it this way:

- If you called a C function `jl_sizeof`, you'd have to pay the penalty of a function call, which is [quite expensive](http://ithare.com/wp-content/uploads/part101_infographics_v08.png) compared to many elementary CPU instructions. If, for example, Julia's `getindex` (which supports array access `A[i,j]`) were implemented in such a way, then Julia would not be considered a fast language---it's fast only because ultimately `getindex` results in inline LLVM IR (for those cases where type inference succeeds).
- C lacks Julia's amazing flexibility with types and heavily-overloaded functions: you'd have to call something more akin to a C++ template specialization, and the reality is that emitting LLVM is just plain easier than having the compiler effectively write C++ for you (it is, in fact, the whole point of LLVM).

If you want to know more about the IR generation, the best resource I've found is the [LLVM kaleidoscope tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/). It takes some time to work through the tutorial far enough to be useful, but it will definitely de-mystify some of Julia's internals.